# Error para fechar form

Tags: visual-basic-6

O que poderia estar acontecendo, pois quando mando fechar um form com unload me, está dando o seguinte erro :

Unable to unload within this context

Comment: É possível que o formulário ainda não esteja carregado, você está executando o "Unload" dentro do evento "Load" do formulário?

Comment: DavidTerra - Nesta parte é certeza o formulário é carregado e pelo que andei verificando acabei encontrando o link abaixo mas no meu caso não tenho nada também relacionado ao resize, continuarem na pesquisa. Conforme abaixo : Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
   On Error GoTo TryCathError
   Unload Me
   Exit Sub
TryCathError:
   Dim s_dsMsg As String
   ...     
End Sub

link ===> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243662(v=vs.60).aspx 

There is an Unload statement in the Resize event of a Data, Form, MDIForm, or PictureBox control. 
Remove the Unload statement from the event.

Comment: Por favor edite a sua pergunta e ponha nela o trecho de código com a abertura do formulário e também o ponto onde está ocorrendo o erro.